# Repetition of indefinite article with several adjectives

Tags: adjectives, indefinite-articles, parallelism, repetition, conjunction-reduction

> Sindbad was a rich and a famous sailor.
>   Sindbad was a rich and famous sailor.

Which of these are correct?
What is the general rule for using articles before a noun with two adjectives?

Answer (score 3):

The second one is correct. The first one makes it sound as if he is a 'rich' (not a noun) and a 'sailor,' who is famous for being a sailor.

---

I can't think of a situation where you would use the indefinite article (a/an) twice in a single noun phrase. In most cases, you wouldn't use the definite article twice either to describe the same thing.

> *The green and the blue marbles

clearly means two separate groups of marbles.

The exception, you can use multiple (definite) articles with superlatives, but it sounds stilted and kinda anachronistic.

> Isaac Newton was the greatest and the luckiest of the mortals.

(From the New York Public Library: http://web-static.nypl.org/exhibitions/newton/introduction.html)

These adjectives use the definite article because you *must* be referring to a definite noun when using them. You can't say `a greatest mortal`. I would argue that the "the" can be analyzed as a necessary part of the superlative, at least in writing.

Comment: Do you have an authoritative source that supports one or the other? I'm not really sure which one you're advocating, after you said "On second thought...".

Comment: Do my edits clarify?

Comment: It's a stylistic thing. See [A Brave and a Good Idea](https://hbr.org/2015/04/selling-ge-capital-was-both-a-brave-and-a-good-idea). It's slightly more poetic but not incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The first construction is rare, and likely to be used only as part of a poetic or literary style.

In normal everyday speech and writing, use the second example.